# Alternative renderer engine to UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, drupal, uiwebview

We want to render HTML5 / javascript rich content in our site. And `UIWebView` crashes meanwhile. Any alternative web component that could help?

Btw we are want to render a `Drupal` website in `UIWebView`.

---

Meantime I tried `WKWebView` because it has the more advanced JavaScript rendering engine called nitro, but app is still crashing.

BTW crash is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in an animation release method

App does nothing else, just tries to load in a page:

```
var urlString = "http://www.weact.ch"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
if let url2 = url {

    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url2))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any more info, such as what is causing the crashes (crash logs might contain clues)? Are you using Cordova/Phonegap or a custom app for the UIWebView? How does mobile Safari handle the Drupal site? Oh, and have you tried WKWebView?\

Comment: if you are 100% sure that your Javascript code is ok, you can try to compile it into optimised Javascript code with something like [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) first and then make a try.